# How to insert data from flat file using space as delimiter in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, flat-file, separator

I'm a newbie in SSIS, and my first tutorial using SSIS was trying to import a flat file or text file which contains data, and my data looked like this:

```
FirstName LastName MiddleName FullName Alias
AA        BB       CC         DD       EE
```

I wanted to insert the data into a table on my database. I can't get it done because I cannot find the space delimiter on SSDT. Only `{CR}`, `{LF}`, `{;}`, `{,}`, etc. but I can't find the space.

Does anyone know how to insert the space as delimiter, and use it so I can import the data on my flat text and insert it to the table.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing, did you find the solution for that or u did as mentioned below in answer?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a fixed width file, and columns are defined by position. In other words, last name defined as data starting at position 10, with a length of 10 characters.

If this is the case, try using the `Derived Column` transform, and use `SUBSTRING` in your expression. [[reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137541.aspx)]